# Is there a way to use jQuery JSONP in CodeIgniter without turning on query strings?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, query-string, jsonp

My code is as follows:

```
$.getJSON("http://xx.xx.x.x/directory/index.php?c=json&m=get_listing&jsoncallback=?", { action:'listings' }, function(data) {
// code
});
```

This works just fine. But now I'm having a lot of troubles with other libraries that don't play friendly with query strings being enabled. If I turn query strings off, and change the URL above to:

```
http://xx.xx.x.x/directory/index.php/json/get_listing/jsoncallback=?
```

Doesn't work. Any ideas on a work around?

EDIT:

When I turn off query string, and use this:

```
http://xx.xx.x.x/directory/index.php/json/get_listing/jsoncallback=?
```

Safari's console shows the following error:

```
GET http://xx.xx.x.x/directory/index.php/json/get_listing/jsoncallback=jQuery17102770626428537071_1329431463691?action=categories&_=1329431463695 400 (Bad Request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. This works:

```
http://xxx.xx.x.x/directory/index.php/json/get_categories/?jsoncallback=?
```

Answer (score 0):

If the last segment is for instance 7, the url must be composed as:

```
http://xx.xx.x.x/directory/index.php/json/get_listing/jsoncallback/7
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. Confused as to why I'd need to put in the segment number.

Comment: Well, I dont know all structure, just tell the principle. If you dont pass some special chars into the url there mut be no problem. So compose the url as http://domain.com/index.php/class_name/method_name/params_segment/other_param_segment/...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is someone still interested in this?
I just made a test on my website to combine Angular, Jsonp and CodeIgniter and it works great.
But i'm concerned by the security implications.
 If someone have a recommendation on this i will be grateful

Instead of sendig the paramteres directly to the controller url as here:

```
public function getObjectJson($page=null,$limit=null,$search=null){

    if($page==null||$page<1){
        $page=1;
    }
    if($limit==null||$limit<1){
        $limit=10;
    }

    $objects=$this->Objects_model->getObjectsJson($page,$limit,$search);

    echo $objects;

}
```

Send them in the url as a query and get them with the respective method in the controller:

```
public function getObjectsJsonp(){
    $page=$this->input->get('page');
    if($page==null||$page<1){
         $page=1;   
    }
    $limit=$this->input->get('limit');
    if($limit==null||$limit<1){
       $limit=10;
    }

    $search=$this->input->get('search');

    $objects=$this->Objects_model->getObjectsJson($page,$limit,$search);

    $var=$this->input->get('json_objectCallback');

    echo $var.$objects;
}
```

And in my Angular factory the URL string is set as a query

```
objectsApp.factory('objectsFactory', ['$http',function($http) {

return {

    getObjectsP: function(p1,p2,p3) {
        //The callback function is harcoded and the prarmeters comes from the angular controller
        return $http.jsonp("<?=base_url()?>Objects/getObjectsJsonp/?callback=json_objectCallback&page="+p1+"&limit="+p2+"&search="+p3).then(function(result) {
          objects = result.data;
          console.log(objects);
          return objects;
        });
    }

}]);
```

Hope it helps.